# Weird corruption problem with http uploads

Tags: http, windows-xp, corruption, upload, windows-xp-sp2

My brother has a computer running Windows XP with SP2 installed.  His computer was behaving badly (very old installation of Win) and one of the problems was that he could not upload jpegs to Facebook, for example.  The upload would complete, but the images are garbled.

Finally I decided it was time to format his computer and reinstall windows, which I did.

Still, images would upload garbled to Facebook.  I tried using Google Chrome instead of IE, same problem.  Then I discovered that this is not just a problem with image uploads,  all HTTP uploads seem to fail.  For example, I could not send an e-mail with an attachment on his computer using G-mail, the attachment got corrupted.

Any ideas?  I don't really know where this problem originates.

1. Happens in different browsers
2. Win XP has been re-installed
3. Just got a new xDSL router (the wired lan section on the old one seized), but same problem

Comment: You might try tracing the request with Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and ensure that what's leaving the machine is what you expect. You could even run Fiddler on another computer to ensure that anything at the WinSock layer is caught.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I believe a little more research is exactly what I need to do :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible his network is glitching?  The only correctness check on a HTTP upload is the Content-Length header and even that's option (and frequently unchecked by the receiving end anyway).  If his TCP connections are dropping then the receiving end could think it has a full image but really have gotten only the beginning of it.

Comment: You are probably right, it's like the network is glitching.

Other machines on the same LAN, albeit on the WIFI are not having this problem as far as I know.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm not going to get a step-by-step solution to this problem of mine, it's a bit too weird for that :-)

Ry4an is probably right on the money, but I'll need to figure out what is causing this.

Any other comments?

Comment: I'd be firing up wireshark were I in your shoes.  Failing that try uploading to a web server you control and see what the received image looks like.  Is it truncated or corrupted?

Suspect the cable.